# Turn text into smileys

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

Just a simple and maybe stupid question but. I'm looking for a way to turn example. `":)"` Into some kind of image that displays instand. I don't know if there is a plugin for it, or if it is something you need to code yourself.

Comment: What context is that text in, certain parts of the DOM? In a general case use a find and replace approach, find the text `":)"` and replace it with a `<img ...>`.

Comment: Also is this question more about JavaScript or C#? Because C# doesn't really seem to fit based on the other tags.

Comment: i would recommend using unicode instead of images so that it loads fasts and appears in <textarea>s ☹☺☻, as well as being super-easy to replace with, since the inputs and outputs are both strings with no outside dependencies like images or css classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a plugin you can use: http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/

Works like this:

```
<div class="comment">
  Hi, this is a great plugin! :-)
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$('.comment').emoticonize();
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I can't make it work, i placed the links at the top, an wrapped the <div class="comment"> around my comment model like so: 
<div class="comment">
           <p style="word-wrap:breakword;">@comment.Content</p>
</div>

Any idea what's wrong, and yes i addede the $('.comment').emoticonize(); at the bottom of the page

Comment: Did you download the files and add them to your project? :)

Comment: Faceplam xD Belived they was onnline hostede xD

Comment: It should be fine. But if the modal content is loaded after you've already used the emoticonize method, you might have to use it again (on the content in the modal).

Answer (score 0):

it is so easy.

```js
String.prototype.Smiley = function(obj) {
    var retStr = this;
    for (var x in obj) {
        retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), '<img border="0" src="./smiley/'+obj[x]+'">');
    }
    return retStr;
};

var sm_codes = [":)":"happy.png", ":(":"upset.png"];

var text = 'Hello :) how are you? oh im upset :('.Smiley(sm_codes);
```

all your Smiley images must be in ./smiley/ folder.

Comment: While your code looks fine, it's a good idea to explain your answer. It might not be obvious to the OP.